# convert uiivew to image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

hello guys i am trying to convert objective-c code to swift i did it but i got error 
and here is my code

```
 func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img!

}

@IBAction func uploadbutton(_ sender: Any)
{
    let viewcontroller = newViewController()

    viewcontroller.self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newViewController")
    viewcontroller.uiimageview = self.imageWithView(view: view1)
    self.present(viewcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

and i got error in the code : **cannot assign value of type 'UIImage' to type UIImageView**

```
viewcontroller.uiimageview = self.imageWithView(view: view1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend editing your question. It sounds (from your comments) that you wish to:

- Take a `UIView` and create a `UIImage`
- Take that `UIImage` and use it in a `UIActivityViewController`

You don't need to do anything more than that! Let's say you *already* have `UIViewController` that is displaying (1) the view you wish to upload, including it's subviews, and (2) has a button to show the options to share. Here's how to accomplish *both* of these:

- Here's an extension that takes a view (and it's subviews) and returns a `UIImage`.

  ```
  extension UIView {
      public func createImage() -> UIImage {
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(
              CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height), true, 1)
          self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
          let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
          return image!
      }
  }
  ```
- Now that you have a `UIImage`, just simply present a `UIActivityViewController`:

  ```
  @IBAction func shareImage(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
      var shareImage = myView.createUIImage()
      let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareImage], applicationActivities: [])
      vc.excludedActivityTypes =  [
          //UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
          //UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
          UIActivityType.postToWeibo,
          //UIActivityTypeMessage,
          //UIActivityTypeMail,
          UIActivityType.print,
          //UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
          UIActivityType.assignToContact,
          //UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
          UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
          //UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
          UIActivityType.postToVimeo,
          UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo
      ]
      present(vc,
              animated: true,
              completion: nil)
      vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
      vc.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activity, success, items,  error) in
      }
  }
  ```

I typically include all excluded UIActivityTypes (even those I comment out) to remind me of those I'm including.

Comment: thank toy sir so much it's work <3, but it's save with bad quality

Comment: That code is from a couple of apps - the conversion is a watermark I created and it looks good (when my IAP hasn't been used!) and the activity controller is, well, obvious. What kind of save are you using? To the camera roll? What is the quality issue?

Comment: The picture is not as clear as that of the program
i used Email and twitter

Comment: One last question - I don't have that issue but am not sure why - could you let me know two things (I'm assuming you are converting a `UIView` to a `UIImage`)? What is (a) the `UIView` frame size and (b) the resulting `UIImage` size?

Comment: the view size is -- width 375 and height: 1,200 , and the uiimage same size , i think because i use Scroll View

Comment: I'll look into this. I use auto layout, with my watermark set to 40% of the actual image height/width so it fluctuates. Let me see why a 375x1200 view with subviews isn't clear. Do you have any *actual* images in this view?

Comment: yeah i have image and textlabel , i put a white image as UIImage

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - what is a white image? I was asking because images *may* not work in the conversion from `UIView` to `UIImage`. I never tried that. (Scaling, aspects, etc.) I'm thinking that's where the quality is the issue - what are you (high level) trying to do? I know we're getting way off topic on "Objective-C", but I'm trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

try `viewcontroller.uiimageview.image = self.imageWithView(view: view1)`

the image view is just a view container that will contain the image property

Comment: i got error ` Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Comment: i use button action becuse i want to convert UIviewController to UIImage and use UIActivityViewController to send it as UIImage

Comment: could you clarify converting UIViewController to UIImage? so newViewController is your UIActivityViewController?

Comment: i want to convert my newViewController as uiimageview and use UIActivityViewController ,

Comment: could you edit your question to include code for newViewController()? I can't really get the structure and your intentions

Answer (score 0):

Result of `imageWithView(view:)` is an UIImage but you assign it to a UIImageView object.

`viewcontroller.uiimageview.image = self.imageWithView(view: view1)`

Comment: i got error ` Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`